# Disabling the site cache brakes the page output

Tags: views, theming, 8, caching, media

I have just finished my development and uploaded a website to a hosting. But unfortunately I've got another weird problem..

If I disable the site cache another template is used for rendering a view node. 
I cannot catch the error. The problem is that in case I disable all caches, this problem appears. But when I try to debug the problem it disappears)) 
So I am not able to find what is wrong with it ?
Sometimes it appears after commenting these lines

```
#$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
#$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

Sometimes it appears after disabling `Twig Debug`

The problem that it swaps view node templates between two views. For exampl I have a view for rendering teasers, and another view is for rendering a node preview. So it swaps them. I really cannot understand what is going on and what is the problem.

Please suggest what can cause such weird behavior ?

Thanks

**NOTE 1**

The same problem occurs locally when I disable caches.

**NOTE 2**

I've found the weird part of debug output

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_unformatted__latest_works' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x views-view-unformatted--latest-works.html.twig
   x views-view-unformatted--latest-works.html.twig
   * views-view-unformatted.html.twig
-->
```

The same template is suggested twice

**NOTE 3**

I've noticed another weird behavior

```
#$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
#$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

Comment these lines the view on the main page doesn't work, outputs nodes with template from another page.
Go to menu, Devel -> Clear Cache. 
Now view on the main page works correctly, but on the other page output nodes using template from the main page.

And these behavior repeats

**FINALLY**

The problem is caused by the render cache I guess. To get this error I have to do following steps :

1. Consider there are two pages the `front` and the `category` page.
2. If current page is displayed incorrectly, then stay on this page open admin panel, clear the site cache, refresh the page - everything is rendered correctly.
3. Go to the category page, now it rendered incorrectly and nodes that are also present on the `front` page rendered incorrectly using the `front` page template.
4. If I clear cache again and refresh the category page it will work, but the front page will be rendered using the view template from the category page.

I hope I've described the problem clearly.
It seems that the problem is similar to that one https://www.drupal.org/node/2359955

Comment: Have you completely flushed the cache and is anything like memcache being used? Does the server have enough PHP memory?

Comment: @Kevin, thank for the reply, yes I cleared all caches, the same problem appears locally when I turn off the cache

Comment: @Kevin please see my notes, I've added some information

Comment: @Kevin I've reproduced the problem, please see my update

Comment: That's not similar to the issue you linked, it *is* that issue. Per-view node templates don't work. Don't use them, define and use separate view modes.  That's the only solution right now.

Comment: @Berdir, could you please explain this in greater details ? And post it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found a temporary solution to this problem.

Edit `core/includes/entity.inc`

Comment reset check lines.

```
function entity_view(EntityInterface $entity, $view_mode, $langcode = NULL, $reset = FALSE) {
  $render_controller = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder($entity->getEntityTypeId());
  //if ($reset) {
    $render_controller->resetCache([$entity]);
  //}
  return $render_controller->view($entity, $view_mode, $langcode);
}
```

If someone has the same problem, please let me know whether the solution works.